# Common point for parallel lines(segments)

Tags: functions, geometry

What formula can get a first common point(horizontal) for two parallel lines(segments)?
A couple of examples:

[image: First example]
[image: Second example]
[image: Third example]
[image: Fourth example]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** Interactive visualization using `IntervalSlider`s:

```
DynamicModule[{i1 = {5, 10}, i2 = {6, 11}}, 
 Panel@Column[{Row[{Style["interval 1    ", 16, ColorData[97]@4], 
      Dynamic@Pane[i1[[1]], Alignment -> Right, ImageSize -> {40, 20},
         BaselinePosition -> Center], 
      IntervalSlider[Dynamic[i1], {0, 20, 1}, Method -> "Stop", 
       Appearance -> {"Paired"}, ImageSize -> 400], 
      Dynamic@Pane[i1[[2]], Alignment -> Left, ImageSize -> {40, 20}, 
        BaselinePosition -> Center]}, Spacer[10]], 
    Row[{Style["intersection", 16, ColorData[97]@2], 
      Dynamic@Pane[If[Max[Min /@ {i1, i2}] > Min[Max /@ {i1, i2}], " ", 
         Max[Min /@ {i1, i2}]], Alignment -> Right, 
        ImageSize -> {40, 20}, BaselinePosition -> Center], 
      Dynamic@Graphics[{If[Max[Min /@ {i1, i2}] > Min[Max /@ {i1, i2}], 
       {Thick, Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {20, 0}}]},
       {Orange, CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[7],
         Line[{{Max[Min /@ {i1, i2}], 0}, {Min[Max /@ {i1, i2}], 0}}],  
        Thick, Gray, Line[{{0, 0}, {20, 0}}],
        Black, PointSize[Medium], 
            Point@{{Max[Min /@ {i1, i2}], 0}, {Min[Max /@ {i1, i2}], 
              0}}}]}, 
      ImageSize -> 400], 
      Dynamic@Pane[If[Max[Min /@ {i1, i2}] > Min[Max /@ {i1, i2}], " ", 
         Min[Max /@ {i1, i2}]], Alignment -> Left, 
        ImageSize -> {40, 20}, BaselinePosition -> Center]}, 
     Spacer[10]], 
    Row[{Style["interval 2    ", 16, ColorData[97]@1], 
      Dynamic@Pane[i2[[1]], Alignment -> Right, ImageSize -> {40, 20},
         BaselinePosition -> Center],
      IntervalSlider[Dynamic[i2], {0, 20, 1}, Method -> "Stop", 
       Appearance -> {"Paired"}, ImageSize -> 400], 
      Dynamic@Pane[i2[[2]], Alignment -> Left, ImageSize -> {40, 20}, 
        BaselinePosition -> Center]}, Spacer[10]]}, 
   Spacings -> {0, -.5}, Alignment -> Center]]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Using `NumberLinePlot` and `IntervalSlider`:

```
nlP = NumberLinePlot[{Interval@First@#, 
     IntervalIntersection @@ Interval /@ #, 
     min = Min[IntervalIntersection @@ Interval /@ #], 
     Interval@Last@#}, 
    Epilog -> If[min === DirectedInfinity[1], {}, 
      Text[Style[min, 14], {min, 2}, {3, 0}]], 
    Spacings -> {1, 1, 0, 1}, 
    Ticks -> {{#, Style[#, 14]} & /@ Flatten[#], Automatic}, ##2, 
    ImageSize -> 1 -> 30, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 4}}] &;

DynamicModule[{i1 = {5, 10}, i2 = {6, 11}}, 
 Panel @ Column[{Row[{Style["interval 1    ", 16, ColorData[97]@4], 
      Dynamic@Pane[i1[[1]], Alignment -> Right, ImageSize -> {40, 20},
         BaselinePosition -> Center], 
      IntervalSlider[Dynamic[i1], {0, 20, 1}, Method -> "Stop", 
       Appearance -> {"Paired"}, ImageSize -> 300], 
      Dynamic@Pane[i1[[2]], Alignment -> Left, ImageSize -> {40, 20}, 
        BaselinePosition -> Center]}, Spacer[10]], 
    Row[{Style["interval 2    ", 16, ColorData[97]@1], 
      Dynamic@Pane[i2[[1]], Alignment -> Right, ImageSize -> {40, 20},
         BaselinePosition -> Center],
      IntervalSlider[Dynamic[i2], {0, 20, 1}, Method -> "Stop", 
       Appearance -> {"Paired"}, ImageSize -> 300], 
      Dynamic@Pane[i2[[2]], Alignment -> Left, ImageSize -> {40, 20}, 
        BaselinePosition -> Center]}, Spacer[10]], 
    Dynamic[Panel[#, ImageMargins -> 10] &@
      nlP[{i2, i1}, ImageSize -> 1 -> {30, 25}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 4}}, 
       PlotStyle -> (Directive[CapForm["Round"], #,                 
            AbsolutePointSize[5], AbsoluteThickness[7]] & /@ 
         {ColorData[97]@1, ColorData[97]@2, Black, ColorData[97]@4})]]}, 
   Spacings -> {0, -.5, 1.5}, Alignment -> Center]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[f]
f[i__Interval] := Min @ IntervalIntersection[i] /. Infinity -> {}

f[l__Line] := Module[{int = Interval /@ Sort[{l}[[All, 1, All, 1]]]}, f @@ int]
```

***Examples:***

```
f[Interval[{5, 10}], Interval[{6, 11}]]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

```
f[Line[{{5, 1}, {10, 1}}], Line[{{6, 2}, {11, 2}}]]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

```
f[Interval[{5, 100}], Interval[{7, 9}]]
```

> ```
> 7
> ```

```
f[Interval[{5, 10}], Interval[{11, 15}]]
```

> ```
>  {}
> ```

Comment: Similar approach for `Interval`s: `ArgMin[{x, And @@ (Element[{x}, #] & /@ {##})}, x] &`.